# How can i check the data base name already exists or not in sql server using java?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I want to check whether the database name is alredy exists in sql server 2008 or not.
If it's not means i need to create the database.
How can i check this?

Comment: for example i want to check if the database `example`is already existed or not. if it's not means i need to create `example` database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if it NOT EXISTS:

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = N'YourDBName')
CREATE DATABASE [YourDBName]
```

Or you can check if it EXISTS then drop it:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = N'YourDBName')
DROP DATABASE [YourDBName]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection();
ResultSet resultSet = connection.getMetaData().getCatalogs();

while (resultSet.next()) {
    // Get the database name
    String databaseName = resultSet.getString(1);
}
resultSet.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show databases;` SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in a startup query, combine the two actions using `create if not exists` SQL statement (see your DBMS actual documentation for the exact syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.is_db_exists
(
    @db_name NVARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS INT
AS BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM sys.databases 
        WHERE name = @db_name
    ) RETURN 1

    RETURN 0

END
```

Or this this query -

```
IF DB_ID('<db_name>') IS NOT NULL
   PRINT 'DB is exists'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sp_databases` command  in sql server query window